# Inserting n elements from xml layout to LinkedList (Android)

Tags: android, xml

I have n CheckBox elements in my XML layout for a user registration page. My XML is as follows:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 2" />
```

How can I add those elements to a LinkedList of type CheckBox in my java code? Ideally, I'd like to use a for-loop to find all elements containing ID "checkbox."

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You could traverse through the parent view (let's say it's called `resultView`).

```
        List<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (resultView.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
                // this is a check box for sure
                boxes.add((CheckBox) resultView.getChildAt(i));
            }
            if (resultView.getChildAt(i).toString().contains("checkbox")) {
                // this might be a checkbox, and may cause ClassCastException
                boxes.add((CheckBox) resultView.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your CheckBoxes are in the same parent view, you can try to loop for it's children like :

```
List<CheckBox> list = new LinkedList<>();

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
   View child = layout.getChildAt(i);

   //Some condition to get the view you want 
   //and make sure it's a CheckBox (maybe by tag?)

   list.add((CheckBox)child);
}
```